# Code First define foreign key to "external" table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

In my project I have some tables that are not managed by Code First (the ASP.NET Users and Roles tables). I want to reference those tables from my own tables, just to make sure the data is integral. I am not adding any constraints to the ASP.NET tables, just to my own, so I'm fairly certain this won't bother the ASP.NET membership code.

I have my own Users table which will hold additional user information:

```
class MyUser
{
     public int UserId { get; set; };   // The primary key of the table
     public Guid UserGuid { get; set; } // References aspnet_Users.UserGuid
     ...
}
```

I basically want Code First to execute the following SQL when creating the MyUsers table:

```
ALTER TABLE MyUsers ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserGuid) REFERENCES aspnet_Users(UserId)
```

and I want it to run it properly when performing migrations etc...

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you reverse engineered the ASP.NET users and roles tables into code first land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, I think you need to use the reverse engineer tool to generate the code first POCOs for the ASP.NET umembership tables.  You can then reference these POCOs directly from your MyUser class for example.

Comment: Ah, if only I could do that. The Power Tools fail to run claiming they only support SQL Servers 2008 or lower. I have 2012 on my dev machines...

Comment: Thats a pain, though if the schema hasn't changed for the membership stuff in 2012, I would have thought you could just use POCOs generated off of a 2008 DB?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. But now Code First wants to create the ASP.NET tables during code-migration, which is a real pain. I'll need to manually edit the configuration generated code.

Comment: I'm doing a similar kind of thing to you, but I have decided to put my new tables in a different schema.  This has the downside of not being able to reference the entity across schema directly in C#, but it does get around these migration type issues.

Comment: When I didn't map the classes to Code First, the migration code was blind to them - it didn't touch them at all. I'll just drop the foreign key if this continues being an issue.

Comment: OK, this is working fine, further migrations don't add these tables. I hate touching migration code by hand, though, but for now it will suffice.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.  The other option I saw was to customize the generation of the reverse engineered migration code, http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/